# Copy files in a directory to another directory

Tags: command-line

new to ubuntu and i keep reading the stuff posted but it isn't working for me, help!!! I  am missing something hope someone can help. I am trying to copy files from one folder to another. when i do this it copies all folders into the the folder. the problem is i didnt want copies of all the folders i just wanted the files in the one folder to copy to another folder:

```
cp -a /home/troy/Downloads/ . /home/troy/.gs/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and run:

```
find /home/troy/Downloads/ -type f -exec cp {} /home/troy/.gs/ \;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked great i have messed with this for a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use these commands to copy only files to any specific directory**

Suppose you want to copy all the files under `/home/troy/Downloads` to `/home/troy/.gs` then:

First go to `/home/troy/Downloads` and:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I '{}' cp {} /home/troy/.gs
```

If you want to copy any specific file say `*.mp3` then you can execute this command:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -type f | xargs -I '{}' cp {} /home/troy/.gs
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but... So easy operation from user point of view is performed so complicated. I am frustrated.

Comment: @heroin: I'm glad that you commented here. I believe that you just dived in Unix commands. Once you'll get experienced you'll say later how powerful, robust and flexible the commands are.. I can understand your frustration and also can say that you don't know how to use **find** and **xargs** commands. I suggest you to go though it. `man find` and `man xargs` would help you to learn about these commands. **Happy Learning!**

Answer (score 0):

`find` is an incredibly powerful command, but I can't ever remember how to use it.

I realized that off the top of my head I didn't know the answer to your question, but thought that file globs might be useful, so here's what I tried:

```
/tmp/askubuntu $ ls # notice no output because this directory is currently empty
/tmp/askubuntu $ mkdir src dest # create source and desination directories
/tmp/askubuntu $ ls # now we have the two directories we created
dest  src
/tmp/askubuntu $ cd src
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ ls # no files in src, yet
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ touch file-1 file-2 # create a couple of empty files
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ ls # now we can see the files that we created
file-1  file-2
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ mkdir dir-to-ignore # make a directory that we don't want to copy
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ ls -l # we can use 'ls -l' to view the files as well as their types. note the 'd' to the left of dir-to-ignore -- this says it is a directory
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 josh josh 4096 Oct 24 00:06 dir-to-ignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 josh josh    0 Oct 24 00:05 file-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 josh josh    0 Oct 24 00:05 file-2
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ cd ../dest/
/tmp/askubuntu/dest $ ls
/tmp/askubuntu/dest $ touch file-3 # make an empty file here too
/tmp/askubuntu/dest $ cd ../src/
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ ls
dir-to-ignore  file-1  file-2
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ cp * ../dest/ # copy all files from our current directory (* matches anything) to ../dest
cp: omitting directory ‘dir-to-ignore’
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ ls # our current directory is unchanged
dir-to-ignore  file-1  file-2
/tmp/askubuntu/src $ cd ../dest/
/tmp/askubuntu/dest $ ls # but we copied all of files we wanted, and nothing more
file-1  file-2  file-3
```

The reason for this works isn't immediately obvious. Had we given `cp` the `-r` flag (so `cp -r * ../dest/`), we would have also copied over `dir-to-ignore` in addition to all of its contents. This is because `-r` indicates to copy directories recursively (as we can see by typing `man cp` at a terminal).  So in your case this might become `cp -a /home/troy/Downloads/* /home/troy/.gs/`. Or you can omit the `-a` if you desire.

I don't claim that relying on this slightly odd behavior of cp (not copying directories without the `-r` flag, but also not giving an error) is the right thing to do. My goal was to illustrate how I might try to construct a solution to this problem and illustrate a few commands along the way.

Maybe you'll find it useful, maybe you won't, maybe you already know all of this. Just my two cents. But regardless, I think it's nice to know how/why things work and be able to explore solutions on your own.